# Is there a jQuery image slider with "popup function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I've been looking all day for a free jQuery/jQM image slider (or carousel) with a "popup function". By "popup function" I mean: When you click on a image, the image gets bigger, like a popup ([example](https://www.digitec.ch/de/s1/product/philips-pd7022-tragbarer-dvd-player-mit-2-bildschirmen-blu-ray-player-recorder-5315060), click on the image).

I've found a lot of sliders, but non of them could show images bigger, when you click on them.

This is actually what I need [menucool slider](http://www.menucool.com/slider/use-high-resolution-images-when-slider-is-fullscreen). But it has be free.

Is there a *free* image slider/carousel (whatever you call them)?